# PHP Session variable not carrying over

Tags: php, session

I am working with PHP session variables, but the problem is that the session variables are not carrying over. I checked using Firebug, and found that the session variables are not being created at all.
`print_r($_SESSION);` returns an empty array after the page returns to index.php, but displays it correctly before the refresh.
logincheck.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']==true)
{
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Smart Shopping Cart System</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    .show-grid{
        background:#E0E0E0;
        }</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include "connection.php"
?>


//      ** Some Content**
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{

    ?>
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Log In | SmartCart</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                SmartCart
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form role="form" method="post" name="login" action="test.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Operator Username</label>
                        <input type="username" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pass">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>


                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="sub">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body></html>
    <?php

}
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
?>
<html><head><title>Redirecting...</title>
</head>
<body>
Redirecting....
<?php 
include "connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $u_name=$_POST['username'];
    $password=mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $password=mysql_escape_string($password);
    $w="select * from operators where operator_username = '$u_name' AND operator_pass = '$password'";
    $b=mysql_query($w) or die(mysql_error()."in query $w");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($b);
    if($num_rows > 0)
    {

        $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
        $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
        print_r($_SESSION);
       echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=index.php">';
    }
    else
    {
         echo "<script>
          alert('Your username or password is incorrect. Please try again'); window.location = 'index.php'; </script>";
    }
}

?>
</body></html>
```

Please help.

Comment: check `session_id()` in both scripts. if you get a different value, then your session cookie settings are almost certainly wrong, and you're getting a different/empty session.

Comment: session_id() is same. I checked it using Firebug.

Comment: check out $_SESSION["loggedin"]=true;

Comment: also your login page is weak man it should be `if($num_rows == 1)` not `if($num_rows == 0)` Do it that way it will cause problems

Comment: Updated the question. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the under score is missing in on test.php page
in `$_SESSION['loggedin']=true;`
change this to `$_SESSION['logged_in']=true;`

As you are using this in

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']==true)
```

there is no error with you session part the error is may be in you db access part check your database connection. you can check you session by commenting the query part, it is working fine.

Comment: It WAS an error, though changing it didn't changed anything. Session variables are not being carried over (or are not being created in the first place).

Comment: there is no error with you session part the error is may be in you db access part check your database connection. you can check you session by commenting the query part, it is working fine.

Comment: Damn! I had session_destroy() in my connection.php. I don't kow why I ever wrote that. Thank you. Can you please include this comment in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Spot the difference:

logincheck:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']==true)
                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

test:

```
    $_SESSION["loggedin"]=true;
               ^^^^^^^^
```

One of these things is not like the other...

Comment: I editedd the code, and made a mistake while pasting here. Will just correct it. This is not what is causing the error though. `print_r($_SESSION);` returns an empty array after the page returns to index.php, but displays it correctly before the refresh.

Comment: Then enable debug output at the php.ini level. there's no point in doing error_level inside your script, especially when it's AFTER the session_start() call. you could have a "headers already sent" problem and never see it because you don't turn on the reporting until after it's too late.

Comment: Oh, and you're vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You're **DOUBLE** encoding the password and never bother escaping the username. Make sure your query is actually working properly and setting your session variables in the first place.

Comment: It is working properly. As said above, `print_r($_SESSION);` returns an expected array before the refresh.

Comment: yeah, but that means nothing. You can assign anything you want to $_SESSION at any time, even if you've never actually started the session. If `session_start()` in that script failed (e.g. you should check its return value), then you won't have an active session, but can STILL stuff anything you want into the session array. it'll just be lost when the script exits.

Comment: I turned error reporting on t the php.ini level.. Nothing changed.. No errors reported..

Comment: error_reporting and display_errors. e_r tells php what types of errors it should report, display_errors controls where/how those reports are actually seen.